# How to determine the line number of the first visible line of a window?

Tags: window, line-numbers

How to determine the line number of the first visible line of a window?

Comment: If you are *not* getting the line number multiple times each command loop for *various* positions, then using `line-number-at-pos` is okay -- it will get a line number even if `point` is *not* visible:  `(line-number-at-pos (window-start))`  If you *are* getting the line number multiple times each command loop for various positions, then it is faster to move to point and tap into the power of the C-source code:  `(save-excursion (goto-char (window-start)) (format-mode-line "%l"))`  See:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3821/2287

Comment: @lawlist Thanks, your comment answers my question. If you are conformable, please convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the user is *not* getting the line number multiple times each command loop for various positions, then using `line-number-at-pos` is sufficient -- it will get a line number even if `point` is *not* visible:  `(line-number-at-pos (window-start))`

If the user *is* getting the line number multiple times each command loop for various positions, then it can be much faster to move to *point* and tap into the power of the C-source code: `(save-excursion (goto-char (window-start)) (format-mode-line "%l"))` -- see: [A faster method to obtain `line-number-at-pos` in large buffers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3821/2287)  The string can be converted to a number with `string-to-number`

There are some important exceptions to calculating `window-start` prior to `redisplay`, but that is beyond the scope of this question/answer:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10768/2287